# rails 3, scaffolded app, how add own error message to update method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In a scaffolded Rails 3, when 'update' method fails to save, the logic is already there to redirect back to the edit page.

we modified the scaffolded method to do some custom validation logic (after update, but before we render the resulting view

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @thingy.update_attributes(params[:thingy])
      if @thingy.found_warning_101

           WHAT GOES "HERE" TO REDIRECT TO EDIT PAGE
           AND HAVE THE DEFAULT SCAFFOLDING ERROR HANDLING SHOW "WARNING 101"?
           THIS DOES NOT WORK, GIVES MISSING VIEW ERROR, DOESNT FIND EDIT VIEW:

           format.html { render :action => "edit", :notice => "WARNING 101" }
           format.xml  { render :xml => @things.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
           return

      end

    format.html { redirect_to(@thingy, :notice => "thingy was successfully updated.") }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @beep.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

We tried (above) to simply copy the same code that scaffolding creates for the case that .update_attributes fails (followed by return) but we get a missing view error:

```
Missing template thingys/update with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml, :voice], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you want to do this, anyway, here is the way to achieve it:

```
@thingy.errors[:base] << "whatever text you want"
```

In you controller of course.

By the way, the missing template appears to be `update`, not `edit`

Comment: Yes, it's a sort of goofy situation we're handling. thanks for that info on adding the error message. I don't understand why render :action => "edit" throws that error ... something to do with update_attributes has already been called I suppose? my guess is we need a redirect statement to redirect back to the update method again... not sure how to do that though

Comment: yes, we're using that method+view to do the editing that triggers the 'error 101'...

Comment: In the code you show here, there is a 'end' missing and 'return' is to remove but the rest seems ok.